# Android libvlc customize user-agent

Tags: android, user-agent, libvlc

everybody. i'm using libvlc from [this repo](https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk)

works beautifully but the user agent always sends **LibVLC/3.0.0-git** even it has a method setUserAgent where you can specify a custom one. it always adds LibVLC/3.0.0-git, for example if i do:

```
libvlc.setUserAgent("my_custom_user_agent","my_custom_user_agent");
```

it sends to the remote server:

```
User-Agent: my_custom_user_agent LibVLC/3.0.0-git
```

has anyone worked with this library and manage to get rid of LibVLC/3.0.0-git part of user agent ???

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

after pulling my hair for a while. the solution was build the VLC core manually. and modify the hardcoded string that is appending its value in a .c file

in the official repo, file

vlc/lib/core.c

contains:

```
void libvlc_set_user_agent (libvlc_instance_t *p_i,
                                    const char *name, const char *http)
        {
            libvlc_int_t *p_libvlc = p_i->p_libvlc_int;
            char *str;

            var_SetString (p_libvlc, "user-agent", name);
            if ((http != NULL)
             && (asprintf (&str, "%s VLCLib/"PACKAGE_VERSION, http) != -1))
            {
                var_SetString (p_libvlc, "http-user-agent", str);
                free (str);
            }
}
```

this is [the link](http://techfly.top/2017/03/10/start_from_scratch_in_linux_vlc-android_open_source_project/) i used for instructions about manually build it.